# Managing remote sass workflow

Tags: sass, workflow

I'm kind of just getting started with PHP development and using Sass for my css in building a site. I downloaded MAMP and built out the site on my local machine, so the PHP worked great, and the sass was automatically compiled locally for me.

Now usually when I have dealt with a remote site, it's been just with extremely simple static html and css files that I can easily modify remotely.

So I finished the site and uploaded it to my remote server. It all works great, but now I'm not sure about the best way to edit the css. How would a typical web developer go about this? I know I could keep a local copy of my entire site, and then every time I need to make a change, edit the local files, find all corresponding remote files via ftp and override them. But that seems a bit laborious for a seemingly simple task. Is there not an easier way of doing this?

Or is it that Sass isn't really meant for simple projects like this, where I would prefer to just manipulate the remote files right from ftp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would keep a local copy, make changes in the local SASS files, re-compile the SASS files and then upload your new CSS file(s).

It is pretty standard to always have a local copy of a site around simply for the sake of not breaking a site in some way when you're developing it or making changes.

A task runner like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) might ease the workflow once you're familiarized with the tool. I use [LESS](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) to pre-compile my CSS and then have Grunt compile LESS into CSS along with minifying it whenever a save is performed on a LESS file which is done with the [`grunt-watch`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) task.

As for project size, I use a CSS pre-processor on all sizes of projects.

Comment: If I got it up and running with git, is there an easy way to set it up so I could do everything locally and then just like git push to put it live? Would I have to install some software on my server or anything for that to work?

Comment: Unfortunately I think someone else will have to answer that question for you. Barely used git myself. I think it might be possible to not install git on the server if you're using SSH though I very well could be wrong. Not sure if you'd really be saving any steps with that workflow though. It would go something like this: compile locally, push to your repo and then pull from repo on remote server.

Comment: Ok thanks. Just came across another slight issue: if I'm programming for mobile, I can't really test it quickly like I can when it's on my local machine. Is there any easier or standard way to do that?

Comment: How do you test for mobile? I start by re-sizing my browser window (there's also browser extensions). From there I deploy it to a remote testing location so I can test on my mobile devices. For me this usually means having to update a remote CSS file. Whether you do that through Git, FTP or even your IDE (text editor). I use Sublime Text 2 with a plugin called SFTP that can be configured to update remote files when you save them locally, or even work on the sever. A lot of this is discovering tools, their capabilities and integrating them into **your** workflow.